# How can a function access local variables defined on a higher level?

Tags: lua

I'm just starting with Lua, and I have a problem with functions accessing local variables. The naive approach, just trying to access a variable, doesn't seem to work.

```
function fn1()
  print(foo)
end

local foo = "Hello, world"
fn1()         -- Prints nil
```

In this case, I could just pass `foo` to the function (as in `fn(foo)`), but that gets tricky with more complex cases.

```
function fn1()
  fn2()
end

function fn2()
  print(foo)
end

local foo = "Hello, world"
fn1(foo)         -- Also prints nil
```

What is the correct way to access `foo` from inside the inner function? Passing `foo` to `fn1` then to `fn2` would work, but that gets difficult when there are several variables and functions involved. I would prefer not to make `foo` global. Are there any other ways to make this work?

Comment: You might also prefer not to make `fn1` and `fn2` global, unless you need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do [the following](https://eval.in/171718) which puts the local in scope of both the functions.

```
local foo = "Hello, world"

function fn1()
  fn2()
end

function fn2()
  print(foo)
end

fn1()
```

Comment: @hjpotter92 True, but I just copied the OP code and moved the local without doing any further editing.

Comment: The point being that a local variable's scope begins after and below the statement that declares it.